# sorting a default dict python

Tags: python

I have a default dict of following type:

```
 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {573014L: [{564470L: 0.011759742609333696}, {573012L:
 0.99999999999999978}, {573013L: 0.0032456927808054942}, {573015L: 
 0.0032456927808054942}, {573016L: 0.0038420894057914217}, {573017L: 
 0.0038420894057914217}, 
{573018L: 0.0034037733703310181}, {573019L: 0.0034037733703310181}], 573012L: [{564470L:  
0.011759742609333696}, {573013L: 0.0032456927808054942}, {573014L: 0.99999999999999978}, 
{573015L: 0.0032456927808054942}, {573016L: 0.0038420894057914217}, {573017L: 
0.0038420894057914217}, {573018L: 0.0034037733703310181}, {573019L: 
 0.0034037733703310181}] }
```

So for each primary key, I want to sort the list of (k,v) pairs based on their values.

For example. for first key

```
 573014:[{573012:0.9999},{564470: 0.11759}.... and so on... decreasing values order...]
```

How do i do this in pythonic way

Thanks

Comment: @Marcin: for k,v in d.items():
              inner_v = d[k]
              for i_k,i_v in inner_v.items():
                    .. not very pythonic you see..

Comment: Go ahead and put that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the built-in `sorted()` on the values section, but remember that it doesn't sort in place so you'll need to update your dictionary.